# Sign Out button to Present Login View Controller - Swift 5

Tags: swift, delegates

Hi I'm kind of new to Swift and I can't figure this out. I am trying to create a sign out button that would take user to the login page. I used the following two methods but the first one doesn't do anything and the second one is throwing `Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while implicitly unwrapping an Optional value` and it refers to the code with the `customButton`:

```
//this one doesn't do anything 
@objc func SignOut(){

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate
    appDelegate?.window??.rootViewController = vc
}


//this one is throwing an error 
let vc = CustomViewController()
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)



//the Fatal error refers to this code
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    self.customButton.addTarget(self, action: #selector(customButtonPressed), for: .touchUpInside)
}
```

Also, I was wondering if AppDelegate is the right approach or if I should use SceneDelegate. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: in first case i think your window is nil .. thats why its not working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to do this

```
@objc func SignOut(){

    let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
    self.view.window?.rootViewController = vc
}
```

Comment: Works great! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

```
let vc = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(identifier: "LoginViewController") as! LoginViewController
vc.modalPresentationStyle = .fullScreen
self.present(vc, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Please make sure the identifier is matching the one inside storyboard for this `viewController`